# How to set up IE Mobile 7 emulation

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-7-emulator

I have a mobile web app built with jQuery Mobile that works fine across a wide variety of browsers/devices. My client's personal phone runs Windows Phone 7 and has IE Mobile 7 installed. This browser has issues (IE Mobile 9 had issues but I fixed those).

I need to locate an emulation of IE Mobile 7 or an early Windows Phone 7 emulator with that browser to work on this. Currently available WP7 emulators are running IE Mobile 9.

looking for ideas and guidance.